# Why is my answer shown as deleted from the original site when the question is migrated?

Tags: support, answers, migration, deleted-answers, undelete

Example Question: [What happens if my ISP's DNS server isn't available?](https://superuser.com/q/372427).

My answer shows "deleted 20 hours ago", but I have the option to undelete, and [based on past experience](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2788459#2788459), [I can indeed undelete it](https://serverfault.com/q/343057).

So, if it is supposed to be deleted, why am I able to undelete?
Or if it is not supposed to be deleted, why was it deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **TL;DR:** All migrated posts will be automatically deleted after some time.

When a question is migrated, the following happen:

- Answers are deleted
- Question is locked, but the answers aren't.
- Eventually, the question itself is deleted automatically (in about a month)

The fact that you are able to undelete an answer is somewhat irrelevant, since the question will be automatically deleted at some point, and all answers will be deleted along with it.

Even if you managed to undelete an answer to a deleted question, there's a cleanup script that deletes answers to deleted questions. Yes, they are [ready for you](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheDevTeamThinksOfEverything).

Perhaps it would make more sense if it was impossible to undelete answers to migrated questions – regardless of whether the question is deleted or not, but I am not sure the devs will think this is worth their time.

Comment: My [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315153/markdown-syntax?noredirect=1) was posted exactely 1 month ago (Nov 29 at 17:51). The question was migrated at *Nov 29 at 21:28*. If you're right, my answer should be deleted in a few hours.

Comment: @RobW Actually they are deleted in about a month, so it could take a few more days. But it will go away... eventually.

Comment: +1 Your answers sounds plausible. I will add another comment once my answer is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my own tests, I believe that the question should be:

> "**Why are some migrated questions (not) deleted?**"

I have tested the undeletion feature on two of my migrated answers, and got different results. Answers to deleted & migrated questions cannot be undeleted, whereas answers to *just* migrated questions can be undeleted, **refunding the deleted reputation**.

### Not reproduced (deleted question)

I cannot undelete an answer to a [deleted migrated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944292/how-is-stackoverflow-com-be-able-to-automatically-log-me-in-even-after-safaris?noredirect=1). Clicking at the `undelete` link will show a big orange box:

[image: pic]

### Reproduced (migrated, but not deleted)

I have successfully undeleted my [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315153/markdown-syntax?noredirect=1) to a migrated, *but not deleted* question. The reputation from the undeleted answer (including Accept-bonus) will **also** return <sup>Source: me</sup>.

I can also cast undelete votes to someone else's answer:

[image: pic]

---

### EDIT:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315153/markdown-syntax?noredirect=1) was moved on 29 nov at 21:28, and **deleted on** 31 dec at 01:01 (deleted after approx 31 days)
- The (undeleted) accepted answer, however, was deleted at 01:27 (after 26 additional minutes). Somehow, it also contained an undeletion vote.

[image]

Comment: a) The question was not deleted from the original location after migration. b) I can test this current example? But maybe I should give a techie some time to look at the data first?

Comment: Update: I have successfully edited a deleted answer to a deleted & migrated question. Observation: Answers to migrated questions are not locked.

Comment: @RobW This refunding of rep. only happens if you issue a recalc, right?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ I assume so. I haven't hit the recalc button, I only checked my reputation audit at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation/

Comment: @RobW Regardless, you will lose all the rep eventually (see my answer).

Comment: In response to your flag: we can't clear undelete votes, apparently. It'll fade away after a while though if the answer doesn't eventually get undeleted.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ My answer has been deleted, 26 minutes after the question got deleted. See my updated answer, bottom line. I'm especially curious about the pending undeletion vote.

Comment: @RobW The undeletion vote is yours: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8315341/revisions , not that any of this matters. Bottom line is, eventually it all gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is my answer shown as deleted from the original site when the question is migrated?

When a question is migrated, it is closed, and locked. The answers are automatically deleted because, otherwise, they could still be voted (and edited). The alternative would be to lock all the answers, but that would mean that who answered would keep the reputation on the original site (from the votes the answer got before to be locked), and in the site where the question is migrated (once they create an account).

Deleting the answers avoids the users who answered get reputation in two sites.